# In UNIKONG you can impale trolls without killing them (sometimes)

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, unikong

If you stand quite close to a Troll and fire then the rocket-bullet-thing can go straight through the troll without killing it.

If it is not a collision detection thing, is it by any chance a metaphor for the usual internet troll's vaporous and windbaggery ways?

I'm on Chrome 49.0.2623.110 m deluxe jubilee edition.

Comment: _a metaphor for the usual internet troll's vaporous and windbaggery ways?_
That's sounds like a good answer, sir, we take it!

Comment: Allright then :)

Comment: Compile date on the physics engine is April 1 -- just sayin'

Comment: Can you produce an animated GIF of this happening? Preferably with freehand red circles drawn over the part we should be observing.

Comment: What is this GIF technology you speak of?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

With the release of Star Wars: The Force Awakens earlier this year, we really wanted to give people the opportunity to be a stormtrooper.

[image]

Comment: "Best"? [Ehh...](http://ffn.nodwick.com/?p=1412)

Comment: I've always, well sometimes, or maybe somewhat occasionally, wondered what is the point of stormtrooper armor? I mean, it protects against nothing as far as I can tell. When did ever a stormtrooper survive a blaster hit? I am sure a sharp pencil could breach their armor from any angle :-)

Comment: @Grubl3r that question [has already been asked on SciFi.SE](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/38509/what-was-the-point-of-the-stormtroopers-armour-in-star-wars)

Comment: @JGreenwell Ah good one!